# How do I render a "Focus" Z Depth Pass for After Effects?

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

*Question:* **Is there any way to render a "Focus" Z Depth Pass from Blender, where I can specify the "Focus on Object" or "Focus Distance" in the Camera settings and automatically generate a Z Depth Pass that makes the object(s) in focus black and everything else gradually more white, instead of generating a standard Z Depth Pass (where everything close to the camera is black and everything further away is brighter)?**

*Background:* I want to render an animation and apply the DoF blur later in After Effects. However, After Effects' Lens Blur-effect requires a pass where the object(s) in focus is completely black and everything brighter than that becomes gradually more blurry. Exporting a standard Z Depth Pass from Blender is a bit tedious since I have to adjust the colors in the pass in After Effects to make the object(s) in focus black and everything else brighter...

Comment: Do you tried [frischluft](http://www.frischluft.com/lenscare/index.php) already? Or do you really want to use this built-in thing?

Comment: I would prefer if this didn't cost me $199.